# Zooming in Microsoft Paint

Tags: windows-7, zoom, microsoft-paint

I have been using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+MOUSE WHEEL to zoom in and zoom out in Microsoft Paint for a while now. However I noticed that it doesn't work for me everywhere. Actually there are only few desktops where it did work for me. I was looking for any options to enable that but found none.

Does anyone know how to enable that functionality?

Comment: Do you notice any trends regarding where the functionality works and where it doesn't? It could be related to the drivers for the input devices and have nothing to do with paint at all. It seems to work for me with Dell USB mouse/keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the reason was the drivers and the type of the mouse and not Paint itself (as @user1362548 suggested).

It looks like the functionality works fine with usual corded mice. It doesn't work  with my cordless mouse however. Still haven't figured out how that can be reconfigured as this is just a standard mouse from system perspective and there is nothing I can play with really..